# Apache Drill - First start time is high

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

I am running SQL on MongoDB backend using Drill. I am getting response time ~500ms.  But most of that time is spent on "First start" phase. Actual processing in drill is taking much less time(~50ms). Why does "First start" take so much time? I would like to know what drill in doing in that phase and if possible optimise that.

[Fragment profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBcbl.png)

[Operator profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

After the first query Drill creates a lot of cache objects to improve the further work, see `Generated Code Cache` [1], [2], [3] for details, `StoragePluginRegistry` Cache [4].
Also `MongoSchemaFactory` creates cache for your `database` and `tableName` [5], which expires after 1 minute.

Most likely you will get the similar time, if you try to execute your query, when the cache expires.

[1] https://github.com/paul-rogers/drill/wiki/CG-Code-Cache

[2] https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/compile/ByteCodeLoader.java#L36

[3] https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/compile/CodeCompiler.java#L145

[4] https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/StoragePluginRegistryImpl.java#L90

[5] https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-mongo/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/mongo/schema/MongoSchemaFactory.java#L66