# Apache Drill consuming a lot of Heap Space

Tags: hdfs, heap-memory, apache-drill

I am running Apache drill version 1.15 in distributed mode on 3 nodes with 3 node ZK quorum to query a small 150MB csv file.
But, Drill goes ahead and uses 4GB-6GB of Heap memory. For testing i have given it 18GB heap space (32GB memory on all 3 nodes).

After firing 3-4 similar queries in Drill UI, drill used almost 80-90% of available heap memory.

I have default configurations except, 18GB Heap space and 20GB direct memory.

[image]
Also, even after a few mins of query execution, heap memory stays occupied.

I doubt if this is correct behavior from Apache Drill? Or am I missing some point?

Answer (score 1):

HEAP memory usage depends not only on the data source size, but on the complexity of the SQL query too, because for planning optimization Calcite HEP planner creates a big DAG with a RelNode vertices. It uses DEPTH_FIRST algorithm to apply different rules for optimization and then recursively process children to obtain the best logical plan. And HEAP memory is used for that whole process.

Regarding the occupation of heap memory after query performing, Drill uses different [caching mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765626/6081939) to improve next query execution.

If you can find some strange size of objects in heap dump, feel free to ask the [Drill community](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/).